# Getting values ​from django database

Tags: python, django, database

I'm just learning python and django.
I am writing a thing that reads the values ​​in the xlsx file, and if the values ​​​​are similar to those in the database, then the value in the adjacent column in the xlsx file changes to the one I specify

models.py

```
class imgUpload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def upload_xlsx(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = xlsxForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            fileName = xlsxUpload.objects.last()
            fileNameStr = str(fileName.file)
            book = load_workbook(fileNameStr)
            sheet: worksheet = book.worksheets[0]
            for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
                a = sheet[row][0].value
                fileNameImg = imgUpload.objects.all()
                fileNameImgStr = fileNameImg.filter(title=a)
                if a == fileNameImgStr:
                    sheet[row][1].value = str(fileNameImgStr)
                    book.save(fileNameStr)
                    book.close()
        return redirect('xlsx_list')
    else:
        form = xlsxForm()
    return render(request, 'img/upload_xlsx.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

I have achieved that it takes all the values, but does not compare them

Comment: Hint: Try to debug the type and value of `fileNameImgStr` it is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: It compares all the values ​​that are in the database and outputs, but I need it to compare one by one